# Search documents by a column value

Tags: search-results

I have a document library containing multiple folders and documents. To make life easier and content searchable, I created a column called Tag which is a single line of text. I did input some text values in that column so  just to test, I used "Template" word in the column. Now my requirement is:

1. When I search for the word "Template" in the "Search this site", I
   should be getting the document that I tagged the document. However,
   it's not working as expected

Can you please tell how I can set that search?

Comment: Did you wait for the search crawler to reindex your content?

Comment: Yup, I uploaded it 4 days ago along with the tag value

Comment: (a suggestion, not an answer) Can I suggest that, rather than "single line of text" you use Managed Metadata for this purpose. I think you will find it significantly better. There is also an out of the box refiner for MMS fields.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, Mathew. Yes if the indexing part doesn't work then I would go with the MMS option.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to wait for the search crawler to crawl the content?  Also, check under Library Settings ==> Advanced Settings that "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results?" is marked 'Yes' Are you using SharePoint 2013 or Online?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the reply. Yes all the requirements you mentioned are already done on the site. The information was uploaded and tagged 4 days ago so I guess the search crawler option can be eliminated

Comment: Which sharepoint version you are using? if you are using online, you can go to advanced settings and re-index the library.

Comment: So should I reindex all the libraries? Ideally, when a new column is created won't that be automatically mapped in SharePoint?